# Как при нажатии кнопки изменить Label?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Как мне сделать при нажатии кнопки изменение Label. Дело в том, что он не обновляется, а остается старый

Comment: Покажи пример вашего кода с проблемой. У меня все обновляется

Comment: Мне надо чтобы при выбранной кнопке менялся текст. RadioButton если что.          if self.but_a1z26.isChecked():
            self.label_5.setText('Ключ не требуется')

Comment: Вооот, а я думал что у вас QPushButton или QToolButton используется. Так бы дал пример в ответе, а оказалось бы что вам нужно другое. Поэтому и нужно в вопросе конкретизировать, желательно с своим кодом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю такое решение:

- Создаете [QButtonGroup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) и добавляете в него ваши [QRadioButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qradiobutton.html)
- Соединяете сигнал `buttonClicked` к слоту и проверяете кнопку на `isChecked`

Или:

- Подключайте сигнал `clicked` у [QRadioButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qradiobutton.html) к одному слоту
- В том слоте проверяйте `isChecked`

---

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QRadioButton, QButtonGroup, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QAbstractButton


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.rb_ok = QRadioButton('Ключ нужен')
        self.rb_fail = QRadioButton('Ключ не нужен')
        self.rb_foo = QRadioButton('Ключ, возможно, будет нужен')

        self._button_group = QButtonGroup()
        self._button_group.addButton(self.rb_ok)
        self._button_group.addButton(self.rb_fail)
        self._button_group.addButton(self.rb_foo)
        self._button_group.buttonClicked.connect(self._radio_button_select)

        self.label_result = QLabel()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.rb_ok)
        layout.addWidget(self.rb_fail)
        layout.addWidget(self.rb_foo)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_result)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def _radio_button_select(self, button: QAbstractButton):
        if self.rb_ok.isChecked():
            self.label_result.setText('Ключ НУЖЕН!')
        else:
            self.label_result.setText('Ключ... а хз!. -> ' + button.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

**PS.**

Альтернативной `QButtonGroup` будет ручное подключение клика каждой кнопки к слоту (это хороший вариант, если не нужно группировать большое количество кнопок):

```
self.rb_ok.clicked.connect(self._radio_button_select)
self.rb_fail.clicked.connect(self._radio_button_select)
self.rb_foo.clicked.connect(self._radio_button_select)
```

А `_radio_button_select` станет такой:

```
def _radio_button_select(self, checked: bool):
```

Comment: Можно пример как, если вам не сложно, мне просто завтра проект сдавать, а я никак это доделать не могу.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас накидаю :)

Comment: Спасибо большое